# Quais as bibliotecas para desenvolver uma API RESTFul em JAVA?

Tags: java, json, api, restful, http

Sou iniciante em java e gostaria de criar uma API RESTFUL mas não sei qual biblioteca utilizar nem como utilizá-la. Alguém pode me indicar tutoriais bons ou algumas bibliotecas para estudo.

Gostaria de utilizar JSON.

Comment: Já utilizei a biblioteca Jetty (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) para fazer um pequeno WebService REST. Achei bastante fácil para iniciantes.

Comment: Um tutorial básico pra você criar um RESTful em Java: http://www.frigglepop.com/wp/?p=45 Mas recomendo você dar uma olhada no Spring também.

Answer (score 11):

Existem várias opções para trabalhar com REST em Java. Existe uma implementação do [Spring Framework (Spring MVC)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) e o padrão JEE **[JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs.htm#GIEPU)**, que conta com diversas implementações, dentre as quais as que vejo sendo mais utilizadas são [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) e [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy).

Para ver um exemplo de como utilizar o Spring MVC para implementar REST veja [este guia](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). Veja também o [User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) do Jersey, nele há toda a documentação necessária.

Algo que você deve considerar é seu ambiente de produção. Como o JBoss Application Server vem com o RESTEasy, faz sentido você adotar esta implementação caso use JBoss, pois vai facilitar a sua vida. Eu já implantei uma aplicação com Jersey num JBoss AS 7.1 e posso dizer que não foi sem dificuldades, a ponto de precisar alterar arquivos de configuração dos módulos do *container*. Por outro lado, se seu servidor de aplicação é o Glassfish, será mais fácil ir com o Jersey que, assim como o Glassfish, é a implementação de referência.

Comment: Eu uso Jetty e prefiro o Jersey.

Comment: @AndréSalvati O Jetty está na linha lista de "tecnologias que eu preciso usar", mas no meio corporativo só vejo Tomcat, JBoss, Weblogic e Websphere.

Answer (score 6):

Existem diversas soluções disponívels no mercado, mas a que posso recomendar é aprender o padrão. Java EE é um conjunto de padrões, e dentre eles está o [JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs.htm#GIEPU), que é exatamente para REST. Dê uma lida na especificação e veja o site do [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy), que é uma das implementações e possui diversos exemplos.

Comment: Concordo com o jpkrohling e adiciono apenas o play framework caso você esteja procurando produtividade. Mas o RESTeasy é uma boa biblioteca.

Answer (score 5):

A api do SpringMVC é muito boa e simples de utilizar. Utilizamos aqui na empresa em todo projeto e pode ter o deploy com Tomcat/Jetty. Bem leve e simples. [=

Para você ter uma idéia de como é simples o SpringMVC, a classe abaixo já estaria expondo um serviço retornando  JSon:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/carros")
public class CarrosController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<CarroList> listAll() {
        CarroList carroList = // busca a lista
        return new ResponseEntity<CarroList>(carroList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Com ele já é possível mapear a URL do seu sistema, @RequestMapping, o tipo da ação HTTP, RequestMethod e qual será o retorno `produces`.

Aqui tem um exemplo completo onde a comunicação entre view e controller é feita toda com JSon.

O código está disponível no GIT, SVN e no próprio blog. [=

http://uaihebert.com/aplicacao-web-completa-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-e-security/

Answer (score 4):

Eu usaria o [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.com/). Ver também a [documentação específica para Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList).

O arquivo de rotas permite a criação de interfaces REST muito facilmente, como, por exemplo:

```java
# Home page
GET     /                       controllers.Application.index()

# Tasks          
GET     /tasks                  controllers.Application.tasks()
POST    /tasks                  controllers.Application.newTask()
POST    /tasks/:id/delete       controllers.Application.deleteTask(id: Long)
```

Usar JSON também é muito fácil. Outro exemplo:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
...

@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result sayHello() {
  JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
  String name = json.findPath("name").textValue();
  if(name == null) {
    return badRequest("Missing parameter [name]");
  } else {
    return ok("Hello " + name);
  }
}
```

Agora, falando sobre porque o Play! em particular, é permite desenvolvimento de forma muito mais iterativa, onde você usa o browser diretamente para depurar e ver os erros, sem a cerimônia toda de outros alternativas no mundo Java. Desenvolver em Play! é muito mais próximo da agilidade do desenvolvimento em PHP ou Ruby on Rails, mas sem perder as vantagens obtidas com o uso de Java.

Answer (score 2):

Se você está procurando uma solução mais autocontida para criar serviços RESTful, confira o [DropWizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com). Ele integra várias ferramentas e APIs já bem estabelecidas (Jersey/JAX-RS, Jetty, etc) e elimina necessidade de configurar um servidor de aplicação.

Como você está começando, é uma maneira bem rápida de colocar algo no ar (em comparação a ter que aprender assuntos de Spring/Java EE e escolher servidor de aplicação).

**Veja também:**

- [Documentação do DropWizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/) (em inglês)
- [Projeto dropwizard-example no GitHub](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example)